# I can't get my wireless working on ubuntu 12.04. I have a Dell Inspiron 6400

Tags: wireless

As above. I tried alot of the solutions i found in the forum but have had no success. Sorry i'm a bit of a newbie with linux!!

Comment: Tell us the model of your Wireless card by appending this command in your terminal:
lspci | grep Network

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2):

I have that same laptop and had the same problem:

1. Connect to the internet using a modem or cable
2. Use the command `sudo modprobe b43` and see the outcome.

If it doesn't work, open a terminal by opening the Dash and typing `terminal` and clicking on the terminal icon that appears. Then type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Restart computer.(The change only take place when you restart.) Thanks to our friend Karl for this.